# How to locate labels in source code from eventlog produced with `-hd` option

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

GHC RTS can produce several types of profiler logs.
With `+RTS -hd` option GHC generates low level labels starting with package name and ending with a hash like generated suffix:

```
<Language.SQL.SimpleSQL.Parse.lvl958_s3NfS>
```

There is no function name nor file line number, but
the hash must help with locating code contributing to garbage production.

The problem is I cannot find whole suffix `lvl958_s3NfS` in any `ddump` file. I see just first part `lvl958` and it is used in many places in `cmm`, `stg`, `simpl`, and `asm` with different suffixes not equal to `s3NfS`.

```
$ find ./dist-newstyle -name '*.dump-*' \
     -exec grep -o -E 'lvl958_[A-Za-z0-9]+' {} \; | \
     sort -u
lvl958_r3fmP
lvl958_r5UvF
lvl958_r8rJH
lvl958_rhGFx
```

```
$ grep -r -H  'lvl958_'  ./dist-newstyle/ | \
    grep -o -E '[/][^/:]+:'  | \
    sort -u
/Parse.dump-asm-native:
/Parse.dump-cmm:
/Parse.dump-simpl:
/Parse.dump-stg-final:
/Syntax.dump-asm-native:
/Syntax.dump-cmm:
/Syntax.dump-simpl:
/Syntax.dump-stg-final:
```

Comment: I don't think this answers your question but the tool [ghc-core](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core) may be useful here - it spits out the Core and assembly of your program into `less` so you can search for those internal names and (hopefully) see where they're from.